# Check value in dropdown

Tags: validation, vb6, checkbox, combobox

I want to check the value in a dropdown list.  The list is preconfigured to hold a yes or a no.

At the moment, I am using a check box, that looks like this:

```
If chkboxOne.Value = vbChecked And (LenB(txtDetailsRefNo.Text) = 0) Then
    If vblnShowErrors Then Err.Raise 10000, VALIDATION, "A Default Reference Number must be entered."
    blnDataFail = True
  End If
```

Can I simply change chkboxOne to "cboboxOne" by swapping the checkbox for a combobox on the form, and replacing "vbChecked" with True?  I'm not sure how similar their functionality is syntax wise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the item in a combobox you can examine the `listindex` to see whats selected (there is no `value` property)

```
cboboxOne.AddItem "yes"    '//listindex is 0
cboboxOne.AddItem "no"     '//listindex is 1
cboboxOne.AddItem "maybe"  '//listindex is 2

...
if (cboboxOne.ListIndex = 0) Then '// yes selected
```

You can also examine the selected text:

```
if (cboboxOne.List(cboboxOne.ListIndex) = "yes") Then '// yes selected
```

You can also test against custom integers using `ItemData`

```
cboboxOne.AddItem "yes"
cboboxOne.ItemData(cboboxOne.NewIndex) = 42
cboboxOne.AddItem "no" 
cboboxOne.ItemData(cboboxOne.NewIndex) = &HBEEF

...
if (cboboxOne.ItemData(cboboxOne.ListIndex) = 42) Then '// yes selected
```

Comment: Make sure that something is actually selected before those last two, If it's empty, `ListIndex` will be -1 and `.ItemData()` and `.List()` will fail.